# How to add Geofencing on windows phone silverlight 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, geofencing

I want to implement Geofencing on my Windows Phone 8 project, I know that new Geofencing API launched for windows phone 8.1, so I update my project to Windows phone 8.1. Now my project become Windows phone Silverlight 8.1. I want to trigger Notification on background as well as forground when user reach to their desire location. I've Search lot on google but all i found for windows phone 8.1 not silverlight 8.1. I tried to add those example   to my app so its not giving any error, my app is working fine but its not triggering geofence ... Please Can any one help me for this

Here what i've tried in my app may be you can help with this also..

First I have made A class with following code..

```
public class GeofenceService
{
    public static IList<Geofence> GetGeofence()
    {
        return GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences;
    }

    public static void CreateGeofence(string id, double lat, double lon, double radius)
    {
        if (GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id) != null) return;

        var position = new BasicGeoposition();
        position.Latitude = lat;
        position.Longitude = lon;

        var geocircle = new Geocircle(position, radius);

        MonitoredGeofenceStates mask = 0;
        mask |= MonitoredGeofenceStates.Entered;

        var geofence = new Geofence(id, geocircle, mask, false, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Add(geofence);
    }

    public static void RemoveGeofence(string id)
    {
        var geofence = GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);

        if (geofence != null)
            GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Remove(geofence);
    }

}
```

Then Background Task Class

```
public sealed class LocationTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    static string TaskName = "GeofenceUniversalAppLocationTask";

    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        // Uncomment this to utilize async/await in the task
        //var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        // Get the information of the geofence(s) that have been hit
        var reports = GeofenceMonitor.Current.ReadReports();
        var report = reports.FirstOrDefault(r => (r.Geofence.Id == "MicrosoftStudioE") && (r.NewState == GeofenceState.Entered));

        if (report == null) return;

        // Create a toast notification to show a geofence has been hit
        var toastXmlContent = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

        var txtNodes = toastXmlContent.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        txtNodes[0].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode("Geofence triggered toast!"));
        txtNodes[1].AppendChild(toastXmlContent.CreateTextNode(report.Geofence.Id));

        var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXmlContent);
        var toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        toastNotifier.Show(toast);

        // Uncomment this to utilize async/await in the task
        //deferral.Complete();
    }

    public async static void Register()
    {
        if (!IsTaskRegistered())
        {
            var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

            builder.Name = TaskName;
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(LocationTask).FullName;
            builder.SetTrigger(new LocationTrigger(LocationTriggerType.Geofence));

            // Uncomment this if your task requires an internet connection
            //var condition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable);
            //builder.AddCondition(condition);

            builder.Register();
        }
    }

    public static void Unregister()
    {
        var entry = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.Name == TaskName);

        if (entry.Value != null)
            entry.Value.Unregister(true);
    }

    public static bool IsTaskRegistered()
    {
        var taskRegistered = false;
        var entry = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.Name == TaskName);

        if (entry.Value != null)
            taskRegistered = true;

        return taskRegistered;
    }
}
```

and finally I'm calling Geofence function for adding Geolocation and registering Background task and I also declare properly on Packege.appxmanifest. but still not working :(
please your help will be appreciate.